# How do you allow comma to be used for user input for integer based input c++?

Tags: c++

I am pretty new to c++ and I am trying to make a program that prints out the number based on user input. But when you add a `,` it breaks the code since it is not part of integers. What should I do?

I made a simplified code because I want to do more with the integers:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main(){
    int player_input;
    cout << "Insert the number" << endl;
    cin >> player_input;
    cout << player_input;
    return 0; //the code doesn't work if you add a comma in cin when you run such as "3,500"
}
```

Comment: Obviously (?) you have to stop reading integers since a comma cannot be part of an integer. Instead you should read a string (commas can be part of a string) and then write the code to convert a string containing digits and commas into an integer. This seems quite difficult for a beginner to me. But if that is what you want then that is what you have to do.

Comment: @iBug No, because the request is not for comma separated integers, it's for integers containing commas for ease of reading, e.g. 1,000,000 is one million not three separate integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the input in as a string:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
```

---

Remove the commas, using the erase-remove idiom:

```
input.erase(std::remove(input.begin(), input.end(), ','), input.end());
```

which from C++20 you can write like this:

```
std::erase(input, ',');  // C++20
```

---

Convert the string to an int:

```
int player_input = std::stoi(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

With `<locale>`, you might do:

```
#include <locale>

template<typename T> class ThousandsSeparator : public std::numpunct<T> {
public:
    ThousandsSeparator(T Separator) : m_Separator(Separator) {}

protected:
    T do_thousands_sep() const override { return m_Separator; }

    std::string do_grouping() const override { return "\03"; }

private:
    T m_Separator;
};

int main() {
    ThousandsSeparator<char> facet(',');
    std::cin.imbue(std::locale(std::cin.getloc(), &facet));
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/pr2NDG)

Answer (score 1):

I think @Jarod42 is on the right general track, but I don't think there's usually a good reason to define your own locale for this task. In most cases you're doing to have a pre-defined locale you can use to do the job. For example, this code:

```cpp
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cin.imbue(std::locale("en-US"));

    int i;
    std::cin >> i;

    std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

...let's me enter a number like `3,400`, and it'll print it back out as `3400`, to show that it read all of that as a single number.

In a typical case, you'd probably want to simplify things even a bit further by using a nameless locale (`std::cin.imbue(std::locale(""));`, as this will normally at least try to use a locale matching the what the operating system is configured for, so it would support an American entering `3,400`, and (for example) a German entering `3.400` instead.